# How to disable import groups for Java projects in IntelliJ CE?

Tags: intellij-idea

The optimization of imports [seems to be configured in Editor | General | Auto Import](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/settings-auto-import.html). This however doesn't seem to allow to control how imports are grouped (separated with blank lines based on common prefix in package name) and sorted (I'd like to turn grouoping off while still sorting imports automatically and removing unused imports).

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3.4 (Community Edition) von Ubuntu 18.10.

Comment: What do you mean by "disable groups" - disable using "*" in imports?

Comment: @y.bedrov see edit

Comment: If I got you right it's managed under "Imports" tab in "File | Settings | Editor | Code Style | Java"

Answer (score 1):

In order to remove blank lines select the  and remove by clicking on "-" in the Import Layout. Get here by Preferences > Editor > Code Style > Java > Imports

[image]